# Switch back to one workbook after activating another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is as follows:

I have two files opened - `file1.xlsm` and `file2.xlsm`. The first one is active. I want to switch back to the first workbook, every time I activate the second one. I put

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    Windows("file1.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

in a macro module of the second workbook. It doesn't work. Is there a way to do it? Thanks for any help

Comment: Oh, I made it calling a macro with the same statement (Windows("file1.xlsm").Activate). Nevertheless, I don't understand why it doesn't work while putting it in workbook macro module

Answer (score 1):

You have to place

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Workbooks("file1.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

in the ThisWorkbook code window of file2.xlsm (not a macro module).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Call Workbooks("filename.xlsm").Activate
```